# applying management plugin configuration to RabbitMQ failed

Tags: rabbitmq

while running the below commnad from rabbitMQ cmd prompt I got an error saying

"Applying pulgin configuration to rabbit@..falied"

**rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management**

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the below command to restart my RabbitMQ server.

Run RabbitMQ cmd prompt as administrator and execute the below. make sure your command is running under the
 *C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.0\sbin*

the above path depends on where your rabbitmq installed.

**rabbitmq-server restart**